# Cant send multiple images with preview incontact form on html, js + phpmailer.php library

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, file-upload

I have contact form, that`s working, but not how I want to. I need multiple images in input with preview and on submit to send in on my mail. Now i can only preview and send single image.

HTML

```
                    <form class="form__body" autocomplete="on" id="form">
                        <div class="form__left">
                            <label for="form__manufacturer" data-i18n="car_manufacturer"></label>    
                            <input id="form__manufacturer" name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input form__input _req" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form__right">
                            <label for="form__model" data-i18n="car_model"></label>                
                            <input id="form__model" name="model" type="text" class="feedback-input form__input _req" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form__left">
                            <label for="form__engine" data-i18n="car_engine"></label>
                            <input id="form__engine" name="engine" type="text" class="feedback-input form__input _req" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form__right">
                            <label for="form__transmission">Pavarų dėžė</label>
                            <input id="form__transmission" name="transmission" type="text" class="feedback-input form__input _email _req" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form__left">
                            <label for="form__price" data-i18n="car_price"></label>
                            <input id="form__price" name="price" type="text" class="feedback-input form__input _req" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form__right">
                            <label for="form__years" data-i18n="car_years"></label>
                            <input id="form__years" name="years" type="text" class="feedback-input form__input _req" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form__left">
                            <label for="form__phone" data-i18n="car_phone"></label>
                            <input id="form__phone" name="phone" type="text" class="feedback-input form__input _req" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form__right">
                            <label for="form__city" data-i18n="car_city"></label>
                            <input id="form__city" name="city" type="text" class="feedback-input form__input _req" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                            <label for="form__defects" data-i18n="car_defects"></label>
                            <textarea id="form__defects" name="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Defektai"></textarea>
                        <div class="file__item">
                            <label for="formImage"></label>
                            <input id="formImage" accept=".jpg" type="file" name="image" class="file__input" multiple>
                            <div class="file__button" data-i18n="car_photos"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="formPreview"></div>
                            <input type="submit" id="submit.button" value="SIŪLYTI">
                    </form>
```

Javascript

```
"use strict"
// Contact form
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const form = document.getElementById('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', formSend);

    async function formSend(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let error = formValidate(form);

        let formData = new FormData(form);
        formData.append('image',formImage.files[0]);

        if (error === 0) {
            form.classList.add('_sending');
            let response = await fetch('sendmail.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            });
            if (response.ok) {
                let result = await response.json();
                alert(result.message);
                formPreview.innerHTML = '';
                form.reset();
                form.classList.remove('_sending');
            } else {
                Alert("Klaida");
                form.ClassList.remove('_sending');
            }
        }   else {
                alert('Required');
        }
    }
    // Add input file to var
    const formImage = document.getElementById('formImage');
    // Adding div for file preview
    const formPreview = document.getElementById('formPreview');

    formImage.addEventListener('change', () => {
        uploadFile(formImage.files[0]);
    });

    function uploadFile(file) {
        for (let i = 0; i < formImage.files.length; i++) {
            formPreview.innerHTML = '';
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                formPreview.innerHTML += `<img src="${e.target.result}" alt="image">`;
                console.log(formImage.value);
            };
            reader.onerror = function (e) {
                alert('Klaida');
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
        }
});
```

sendmail.php

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
    require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->Charset = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->setLanguage('lt', 'phpmailer/language/');
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    // From who
    $mail->setFrom('test@mail.com','User');
    // TO who
    $mail->addAddress('test@mail.com', 'name');
    // Subject of message
    $mail->Subject = 'Automobilio pasiulymas';

    // Body message
    $body = '<h1>Automobilio uzklausa</h1>';

    if(trim(!empty($_POST['name']))){
        $body.='<p><strong>Automobilio marke: </strong>'.$_POST['name'].'</p>';
    }
    if(trim(!empty($_POST['model']))) {
        $body.='<p><strong>Modelis: </strong>' .$_POST['model'].'</p>';
    }
    if(trim(!empty($_POST['engine']))) {
        $body.='<p><strong>Variklis: </strong>' .$_POST['engine'].'</p>';
    }
    if(trim(!empty($_POST['transmission']))) {
        $body.='<p><strong>Dėžė: </strong>' .$_POST['transmission'].'</p>';
    }
    if(trim(!empty($_POST['years']))) {
        $body.='<p><strong>Metai: </strong>' .$_POST['years'].'</p>';
    }
    if(trim(!empty($_POST['price']))) {
        $body.='<p><strong>Kaina: </strong>' .$_POST['price'].'</p>';
    }
    if(trim(!empty($_POST['city']))) {
        $body.='<p><strong>Miestas: </strong>' .$_POST['city'].'</p>';
    }
    if(trim(!empty($_POST['phone']))) {
        $body.='<p><strong>Telefonas:: </strong>' .$_POST['phone'].'</p>';
    }
    if(trim(!empty($_POST['text']))) {
        $body.='<p><strong>Defektai: </strong>' .$_POST['text'].'</p>';
    }
    // ADD images
    if (!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
        $filePath = __DIR__ . "/assets/images/" . $_FILES['image']['name'];
        // Download file
        if (copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $filePath)) {
            $fileAttach = $filePath;
            $body.='<p><strong>Nuotraukos: </strong>';
            $mail->addAttachment($fileAttach);
        }
    }

    $mail->Body = $body;

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        $message = 'Klaida';
    } else {
        $message = 'Issiusta!';
    }

    $response = ['message' => $message];

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Arleady wasted couple days to figure out how to do it, and still cant do it. Tried to put for there, but did not work.

Comment: Your code sends the upload as soon as one image is selected in the event listener.  Possibly you want to wait until multiple images have been selected and the user actively chooses to send them to the server?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ADyson yes, but I cant understand where exactly I need to  put in loop. I tried before this, but it does not work.
        formData.append('image',formImage.files[0]);

Comment: You don't need to add anything manually there to begin with. `let formData = new FormData(form);` - you are passing the form element to the constructor, so it will automatically encode _all_ eligible form fields for submission. You need to change the name of your file input field though - PHP will _overwrite_ multiple parameters of the same name, unless you use square bracket syntax to generate an array - so that should become `name="image[]"`.

Comment: And then you will of course need a loop over the uploaded files, to add them as attachments to your mail one by one. The structure of the data PHP provides in $_FILES is slightly different when multiple files get uploaded under the same parameter name, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: @CBroe Thank you so much. And also question, how I can preview all of images in html? At this moment, only first image is appearing, even after i changed name to "image[]"

Comment: You'll have to pass just `formImage` to your `uploadFile` function, and then loop over all its files. `formPreview.innerHTML = '';` to clear the preview first - and then you create a FileReader instance for each file in the loop, and append the result to the output area using `formPreview.innerHTML += ...`

Comment: Perhaps consider basing your code on [the send multiple file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps)?

Comment: Thank you very much, both of you. Sadly I cant give you reputation on comment, but you saved me.

Comment: @CBroe I tried to do with for loop, but i am getting multiple preview of first photo from uploads.. I edited JS uploadfile part, what i am doing not right? btw PHP part is working fine now, thanks.

Comment: You are still passing only the first file to the function, `uploadFile(formImage.files[0])`. Then you are looping over `formImage.files.length`, so that it will still iterate for as many times as you have files selected; but then you pass `file`- which is the one first file you gave `uploadFile` - to the reader every time. The latter needs to be the `formImage.files[i]`, so that you access the file corresponding to the current loop index.